# Nginx deny all json files in root directory

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

How can i have location directive for all json files in all subfolders but if file is in root directory it should return 404.

```
 /test.json - 404
 /$anything/test.json - found
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to match files in the root directory. Place the regular expression `location` early in your configuration to avoid other regular expression locations overriding it.

For example:

```
root /path/to/files;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
location ~ ^/[^.]*\.json$ {
    return 404;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

Comment: but how to have other location directive for those that are in any subdirectory?

Comment: That is `location /` which matches any URI.

Comment: It doesn't work.

location ~ ^/[^.]*\.json$ {
    return 404;
}

location / {

 location ~* ^.+\.json$ {
 ...
}

}